# 未翻訳の文字列が使用されている箇所を確認できる機能が欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 却下, 翻訳

### 質問・要望内容

未翻訳の文字列が使われている箇所を確認する確実な方法はありますか？また、もし無いのであれば、そのような機能の導入を要望します。

### 現状の方法

現状は、当該文字列と検索エンジンで使用可能な[検索演算子](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=ja) (例: `site:` 演算子、ワイルドカード演算子など) を用いて検索を行い、検索結果として表示されたページをすべて確認することで、どのページでどのようにその文字列が使われているのかを把握しています。

### 「現状の方法」の問題点

- ログインしなければ閲覧出来ないページの文章や、 JavaScript で追加、変更されるテキストの確認漏れが発生する
- 上記項目に該当しない場合でも、検索結果に表示されないページは無視せざるを得ない
- 使用箇所が発見出来なかった場合、文脈を想像して (もしくは考慮せずに) 翻訳をしなければならない
- 同一の未翻訳の文字列が複数あった場合、仮にそれらの文字列が使用されているページ群がわかったとしても、どの文字列がどのページで使われているかを対応させる作業が生じる

### 問題となる文章の具体例

現在翻訳されておらず、どこで使用されているかわからない文字列の例として、「[How do I ask a good question?](https://ja.traducir.win/string/820)」があります。私が上記の方法で探した限りでは、この文字列がどこで使用されているのかを特定出来ませんでした。

上記文字列の翻訳は「どこのページで使用されているか」がわからない場合でも可能ですが、将来的に「**どこのページで使用されているかわからない**」かつ「**文脈がわからないと翻訳が難しい**」文字列が出てくることも十分あり得ると思います。

さらに、同一の未翻訳の文字列が複数あるとき、それらの文字列が使われているページが（Google検索などで）特定できたとしても、**どれがどのページに対応しているかはわかりません**。結果として、翻訳者がそれぞれに適当な文字列を入れ、翻訳を反映させるなどの方法でページと文字列を対応付け、その後適切な翻訳を適用する、といった冗長な方法をとる事態が生じえます。これはユーザにとっても翻訳者にとっても適切な状態ではないでしょう。

Comment: +1: Transifexの方にはcontextを示すためのコメント機能があるのですが、あまり使われていない＆[Traducirでは現状使えない](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues/117)ので、困っています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu Transifex には説明用のスクリーンショットを貼り付ける機能もありますが、原文の管理者がメンテしてくれないとこちらも役に立たない機能です (他にもタグでの絞り込み等)。 / traducir はボランティアが用意した翻訳ツールという位置付けで、参加のハードルは下がったかもしれませんが、残念ながらかゆいところに手が届いていない印象です。

Comment: 参考: メインの Transifex でも [文字列の文脈や何処で使われているかは分からない](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20086496#20086496) (管理してくていない？)

Comment: For reference, "How do I ask a good question?" is the title of [this Help Center page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in English; [see the English version of that page here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

追加情報として別途投稿いたします。現在、未翻訳の文字列の使用箇所を確認できる機能をコミュニティに提供することは難しく本投稿については[却下](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3738/14055)されましたが、開発者であれば文字列とその使用箇所の確認が可能であるようです。定期的に（例えば、四半期ごとや上半期下半期のどこかのタイミングなどで）、パブリックプラットフォームチームが問い合わせに対応するとのことなので、もしも使用箇所を知りたい文字列がある場合にはどうぞメタで新しくご投稿くださいませ。

Answer (score -2):

未翻訳の文字列が使用されている箇所を確認できる機能の提供が可能であればと思いますが、そのためには翻訳入力が機能する方法全体を再構築しなくてはなりません。Traducir/Transifex は現在、翻訳に利用できる文字列の知識しか持っておらず、これらの文字列はビルド時にアプリに返され、文字列の翻訳を検索するための辞書を作成します。

文字列はコードファイル、js/ts ファイルやビューに配置できます。これらは、サイトの複数のページで使用される文字列を返すビジネスロジックに含めることができます。また、サイト内の複数の場所でまったく異なるコンテキストで同じ文字列を使用することもできます。これにはさまざまな可能性がでてきてしまい使用可能な文字列から派生することは決して実用的ではありません。

したがって、サイト上で文字列が使用されている箇所を知るシステムを構築するには、最初にローカル辞書を作成し（すべての用途から派生させるのではなく）、そこから文字列が使用されている箇所のコンテキスト記述を含める必要があります（それを最新の状態に保ちます）。繰り返しになりますが、私たちが翻訳を行う方法を根本的なところから再構築する必要があります。

暫定的なアプローチの実装（開発者が文字列の使用を検索できるようにユーザーが Traducir にタグ付けを行い、 Transifex と Traducir に使用を追加できるようにする）についても、現在開発者が与えられている可能時間を超えているため難しいです。

そのため、残念ながら、こちらを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)と変更いたします。

Comment: リソースの問題で今すぐの対応は難しいのだとしても、せめて "却下" ではなく "延期" として判断してほしいです。根本的な課題が改善されないのであれば、翻訳作業に積極的には参加したくありません。

Comment: @cubick さん> 恐らく、近いうちに解決できる見込みのものやバックログに追加されたもの以外は延期ではなく却下、というタグ付けの方針なのではないでしょうか。[検索窓の挙動が不明](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3640/32986)も検索機能としての根本的な問題の気がするのですが、却下となっています。