# 検索窓の挙動が不明

Tags: バグ, サポート, 却下

`ja.stackoverflow.com` の検索窓による検索はオイラが勝手に思っている通りに動かないのですが、日本語サイト固有の挙動をしているのでしょうか？

引用はいいんようというオイラ自身の投稿を検索しようとして

例：「いいんよう」で検索（純粋にひらがなのみ記入）→５０００件以上ヒット
例：「"いいんよう"」で検索（ U+0022 QUOTATION MARK を前後につける）→５０００件以上ヒット

後者は match literally だと期待したのですがどうもそうではないようです。
google.com で `"いいんよう" site:ja.stackoverflow.com` と検索するのと同等の結果を ja.stackoverflow の検索窓で得るには何かコツがあるでしょうか？

Comment: つい最近、オイラー・プロジェクト関連の質問が出された際に `"オイラー"` で検索したら面白いことになりました。

Comment: 検索窓をクリックしたら出てくるヒントにも `"words here" 完全に一致するフレーズ` と書かれているので、意図する挙動にはなっていなそうですね。分かち書きが上手くできていないとかあってもおかしくなさそう……。

Answer (score 2):

この問題についてパブリックプラットフォームチームに連絡いたしましたが、残念ながらすぐに修正できるようなものではありませんでした。

このようなサイト内検索のバグを修正することは、特に日本語のような英語以外の言語（ネイティブスピーカーの開発者が不足しデバッグが難しい）の場合、現時点では私たちのキャパシティを超えています。検索の品質（チーム全体でトライしたいとは思ってはおりますが）に取り組む時間を確保できたときに私たちは間違いなくこの問題に対応したいと思っています。ただし、現在はこのリクエストだけに対応する時間枠がないため、現在のところはタグを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)といたします。

Comment: このバグがどうしても課題で、直してほしいとなった場合、ユーザーはどうするのが良いでしょうか？　メタに別の質問をすれば良いですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu  はい、確実なのはメタに別の質問をすることなのだと思います。検索の「バグ」とタグ付けしてどうぞ新しくご投稿ください。時期などは全く未定であるようですが、新しい投稿もこちらも検索についての「バグ」全てが一緒に対処されるとのことです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu: As stated in [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251): "**Old requests that have previously been declined can be reposted as new requests if you have something you can point to as a switch in the platform or culture that would render the previous reasons for declining obsolete.** If you do repost one of these — no matter how old, as long as the issue is still current — be sure to link to the old declined post for historical reference, as well as to any following posts that make discussing the issue again relevant. [...]"